# How to add a Qwt plot to a frame

Tags: python, user-interface, plot, qwt

I have a GUI that is supposed to have a separate Frame for a plot, but for some reason I'm not able to add it like a regular widget. Here is the code.

```
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
          Qwt.QwtPlot.__init__(self, parent)
          plot = Qwt.QwtPlot()
          layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
          layout.addWidget(plot)
          self.setCanvasBackground(QtCore.Qt.white)
          self.container = QtGui.QFrame(self)
          self.container.setGeometry(150,20,100,100)
          self.container.setLayout(plot)
          self.container.show()
```

This gives an error message:

TypeError: QWidget.setLayout(QLayout): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QwtPlot'

Is there some other way that has to be used to add a plot to a Frame?

Comment: I hope my answer solved your problem. I think it's just a typo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is very clear and maybe just a typo:

```
self.container.setLayout(plot)
```

As the method signature says: setLAYOUT. You put in there not a layout but a QwtPlot.

Set the layout you created:

```
self.container.setLayout(layout)
```

You added the plot to the layout, now set this layout.